# Case stement with a compex Sum condition Challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help from the SQL Gods Required

Table 1 - DistinctQuotes

This tables holds information about quotes say .

So we have

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+-----------------+
|REGION | SubRegion | Market Route | Type | Quotations Count|
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+-----------------+
|EMEA   | Germany   | Direct       | DS1  | 12              |
|EMEA   | Germany   | NonDirect    | DS1  | 22              |
|EMEA   | Germany   | Direct       | DS1  | 2               |
|EMEA   | Germany   | NOnDirect    | DS1  | 4               |
|EMEA   | France    | Direct       | DS1  | 4               |
|EMEA   | UK        | Direct       | DS1  | 4               |
+-------+-----------+--------------+------+-----------------+
```

So I want to display the count per Subregion of quotes that have come from type DS1 and Market Route is Direct.

Now this query below is wrong as the count of quotes comes from the sum of the Quotation Count from the matching rows, and not from the count of rows that match 
[Market Route] = 'Direct' AND [Type] = 'DS1'.

Can anyone help me change the query below to capture what I need ?

```
SELECT        
 [Region]  ,[SubRegion]      
   ,SUM (CASE WHEN [Market Route] = 'Direct' AND [Type] = 'DS1' 
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               as [Count of Direct quotes from  DS1] 
FROM [dbo].[V_DistinctQuotes]
  GROUP by  [SubRegion],[Region]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `THEN 1 ELSE 0` to `THEN [Quotations Count] ELSE 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
[Region] ,[SubRegion] ,Count(*) as [Count of Direct quotes from DS1] 
FROM  [dbo].[V_DistinctQuotes] 
WHERE [Market Route] = 'Direct' AND [Type] = 'DS1'
GROUP by [SubRegion],[Region]
```

Comment: The WHERE clause approach can work, but it should be noted that if there is a Region/SubRegion that has data, but not match your WHERE clause, that Region/SubRegion won't be shown at all. *(As opposed to showign it with a count of `0`.)*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you want the count of quotations (actually the SUM of the [Quotations Count] field) where the market route is 'Direct' and the Type is 'DS1' then do the following:

```
SELECT        
 [SubRegion],sum([Quotations Count])
 from
[dbo].[V_DistinctQuotes]
where
MarketRoute='Direct' and [Type] ='DS1'

group by [SubRegion]
```

which yields:

```
SubRegion   (No column name)
France  4
Germany 14
UK      4
```